# How to configure searchkick with multiple elastic search servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I want to set up a different server per model for searchkick.

For example:

```rb
# config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: elasticSearchConfig)
Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Model.client

# This model uses a client pointing to a specific elastic server.
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord 
  searchkick
end

# This model uses a client pointing to another specific elastic server.
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord 
  searchkick
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/1465

Comment: Thank you very much, it is definitely the only way to get it. I had to do a fork to set it up in my legacy project.